# How to install pip?

Tags: software-installation, python, pip, django

The error:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you issued the command when the system was already running an update of some software (automatically or not).  Retry when you are sure no update takes place.

Answer (score -1):

If the problem persists (maybe after rebooting) you can remove the file

```
$ sudo rm -f /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

Comment: This is a bad idea. See the top answer to the linked question for an explanation. -1

Comment: if i remove no problem ?

Comment: @DavidFoerster I know it's not a good answer but in some situations there are no other workarounds.

Comment: @ArghyaHaldar At least for me, there wasn't any problem